# Get session information about Stored Procedure call

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure being called from 1 of 4 web servers.  Inside the stored proc, is there a way to query which server called the stored proc?

Comment: You could open 4 users for that purpose, and differentiate callers according to those users.

Comment: Make the server identify itself by sending a parameter to the procedure.

Comment: The procedure is being called by a dll that I don't have access to change so I can't make any changes to the SP or what gets passed into it.

Comment: take a look to `select * from  sys.sysprocesses where spid=@@SPID`